Send custom routePlan to Juptier API /swap
Hello dear friends hope everybody is good today ?
When following : https://station.jup.ag/docs/apis/swap-api#guide-for-v6-swap-api-code-example
I can't send my transaction to a jito bundle or normal

Get a quote like this :

{
  inputMint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',  
  inAmount: '10000000',
  outputMint: 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v',
  outAmount: '1953696',
  otherAmountThreshold: '1953696',
  swapMode: 'ExactIn',
  slippageBps: 0,
  platformFee: null,
  priceImpactPct: '0',
  routePlan: [ { swapInfo: [Object], percent: 100 } ],
  contextSlot: 300046736,
  timeTaken: 0.010705948
}


Custom quote (RoutePlan), outputMint , etc .... :

{
  inputMint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
  inAmount: '10000000',
  outputMint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
  outAmount: '10000000',
  otherAmountThreshold: '9000000',
  swapMode: 'ExactIn',
  slippageBps: 0,
  platformFee: null,
  priceImpactPct: '0',
  routePlan: [
    { swapInfo: [Object], percent: 100 },
    { swapInfo: [Object], percent: 100 }
  ],
  contextSlot: 300046736,
  timeTaken: 0.010705948
}


Sending to a Jito URL : https://URL/v1/transactions with

  await fetch('https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      quoteResponse : MyQUOTE,
      userPublicKey: wallet.publicKey.toString(),
      wrapAndUnwrapSol: false,
      prioritizationFeeLamports: {
            jitoTipLamports: 10000,
          }
    })
  })
).json();

Don't work and return error :

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined from  transaction.sign([wallet.payer]);

const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(swapTransaction, 'base64');    
var transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);
  const wallet = new Wallet(Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode('5qHsXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXbfDvBf')));
  transaction.sign([wallet.payer]);

A simple quote before swap work good but not when changing quote fetched

The response is : circular are not allowed to POST or getQuote() on public Jupiter endpoint

I'm not familiar with the Wallet type -- since it doesn't seem needed, how about just doing:
const payer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode('5qHsXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXbfDvBf'));
transaction.sign(payer);

Note that I also removed the array [...] in the input.
